# How do I calculate a field to be equal to another?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, file-geodatabase

How can I calculate the StreetNames field to be equal to the values in the TEMP field in the below feature class attribute table?

I am working in a file geodatabase in ArcMap version 10.1.

[image]

Comment: are you wanting to do this in python, or just in ArcMap?

Comment: In ArcMap in the field calculator.

Comment: What version of ArcMap?  What type of database is the feature class stored in?  File, personal, enterprise geodatabase?

Comment: Arcmap 10.1 and it is in a File geodatabase. I'll update my question with that information too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your table, right-click on the column name `StreetNames` and select `Field Calculator...`

[image]

In the Field Calculator window, double-click on the field you want to copy (in your case `TEMP`, in my example I've used `Sub_Unit_Type`) and click OK

[image]

Your StreeNames will now be overwritten by the values in your other field.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With VB script you just make the expression  [temp] and in Python the expression is !temp!  The Field Calculator has a field list to pick from on the left, so you can just double click the field name and it will add the delimiters around the field name.